# How to make a remote procedure call (SOAP client)?

Tags: delphi, soap-client

I have never used SOAP before. Now someone has given me a link to WSDL file and told me to develop an application that makes remote procedure calls to web services which are defined by the WSDL file.

I haven't a clue where to begin ... (XE2 starter edition)

Comment: this is going to be a bumpy ride (:, import the WSDL file(Component -> Import WSDL), a new unit is then created, if you're lucky and the WSDL is imported properly, then you're good, if not, then you gotta' get getto -- download SOAPUI(http://www.soapui.org/), create new project, import wsdl, make requests, see the raw requests and responses, use TIdHTTP and construct your requests through strings or some XML parser, oh, and it can get even worst, if they change the WSDL, all hell can break lose (:

Comment: Don't know how about Starter edition, but if you were having some serious edition, there's a WSDL import wizard from `File / New / Other`, in `New Items` dialog select `Delphi Projects / WebServices / WSDL Importer`. That will generate classes, which you can pretty simply use.

Comment: @TLama off topic, I don't think there's any "serious edition" (:

Comment: +1 to each of you. I have bumped against so many problems with the starter edition that I am about ready to spring for a "Serious edition". However, I looked at a friend's Professional Edition and under Web Services he has only "SOAP server", nothing for client side.

Comment: Ah, he does have Coponent/Import WDL file. Looks liek I am about to srping for an upgrade. And clues as to how to use the generated file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wizard or command-line utility import a published WSDL document and then provide interface definitions and connection information you need.

Documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Using_Web_Services

There are steps for generating interface and code examples.

Take a look at this article : http://www.drbob42.com/examine/examinE2.htm

Comment: The (easiest) answer is to use the WSDL import wizard; but [`not for Starter edition`](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/images/41563/Delphi_XE2_Feature_Matrix.pdf) (see top of the page 13).

Answer (score 7):

There is a Web Service Toolkit compatible with Free Pascal and Delphi. It includes WSDL import and seems to be in active development.

http://wiki.freepascal.org/Web_Service_Toolkit

Comment: +1 for Web services toolkit. I have used this to create enterprise level web services and clients with Lazarus that are still in use today.